# Regular expression Replace tags around a specific string and onclick event

Tags: php, regex

Here is my string

```
<p>Testing is a key element to any application. 
<a href="software-testing.html" onclick="ga('send', 'event', 'internal', 'Node.js', 'Node.js');"> Link1 </a> is called Jasmine. In early 2000, there was a framework for testing  JavaScript applications called JsUnit. Later this framework got upgraded and is now known as jasmine. </p>
<p>Jasmine helps in automated unit <a href="software-testing.html"> Link2 </a>
```

I would like to remove the only   tag into the "**onclick event**" and "**software-testing.html**"  in exact word are match for the Replaces.

I have try following two code

```
 1) <a(.*?)software-testing.html(.*?)<\/a>
 2) \s*<a(.*?)software-testing.html|onclick="[^"]*"[^>]*>((?:(?!</a>).)*)</a>\s*
```

But In my case Link 1 and Link 2 are replaced.

This isn't working. I have searched for days and tried many other options but never managed to get this to work as expected.

Only for Link1 is replace not replace in Link2.

Please help Me.

Comment: Where is your php code? It's not a good ideia parse html with regex

Comment: Why do you not do it in javascript instead?

Comment: Link 1 and link 2 both have `software-testing.html`, dont you want to replace them both? Maybe rephrase the `I would like to remove the only tag into the "onclick event" and "software-testing.html"`. If you just want to remove the onclick couldnt you `str_replace`  the ` onclick="ga('send', 'event', 'internal', 'Node.js', 'Node.js');"`, or the content is dynamic there? Provide more examples please..and/or consider parsing all links.

Comment: I have all Link into onclick event into the value are different. For Ex- 1) <a href="/software-testing.html" onclick="ga('send', 'event', 'internal_linking', 'Node.js Testing with Jasmine', 'Node.js Testing with Jasmine');"> Testing </a> 2) <a href="/interactive-javascript-tutorials.html" onclick="ga('send', 'event', 'internal_linking', 'Node.js Testing with Jasmine', 'Node.js Testing with Jasmine');"> JavaScript </a>

Comment: I was tempted to mark this as a duplicate of [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags) :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could accomplish this using the following *regex* ...

```
<.*?\shref="software-testing.html"\sonclick.*?<\/.*?>
```

see **[regex demo / explanation](https://regex101.com/r/okQStc/2)**

**PHP** ( [demo](https://ideone.com/Sis6Pe) )

```
$regex = '/<.*?\shref="software-testing.html"\sonclick.*?<\/.*?>/';
$str = '<p>Testing is a key element to any application. 
<a href="software-testing.html" onclick="ga(\'send\', \'event\', \'internal\', \'Node.js\', \'Node.js\');"> Link1 </a> is called Jasmine. In early 2000, there was a framework for testing  JavaScript applications called JsUnit. Later this framework got upgraded and is now known as jasmine. </p>
<p>Jasmine helps in automated unit <a href="software-testing.html"> Link2 </a>';
$subst = 'Show me \$1';
$result = preg_replace($regex, $subst, $str);
echo $result;
```

Comment: There is not Replaces for content.

Comment: @RamGuru99 didn't get you. can you please elaborate?

Comment: I have try replaces for link in content but content was not replaces check screen shot only replaces for <a> tag. please check - https://www.screencast.com/t/2pAWBcukRPSO please help me.

Comment: @RamGuru99 umm.. didn't get you properly. can you provide a screenshot of your desired output?

Comment: I want to replace this code (<a href="software-testing.html" onclick="ga('send', 'event', 'internal', 'Node.js', 'Node.js');"> Link1 </a>) with this $1.

My output result i want is - Show me  $1 at the place of Link 1.

Please check Screen shot - https://www.screencast.com/t/lLeqsKuegda

Comment: @RamGuru99 what would be the replacement for `$1` ?

Comment: Replace this code(<a href="software-testing.html" onclick="ga('send', 'event', 'internal', 'Node.js', 'Node.js');"> Link1 </a>) ,With any text.

Comment: @RamGuru99 check updated answer and let me know if this is what you want?

Comment: I have fetch value from database but not getting out please check - https://www.screencast.com/t/5aFFgWBZ

Comment: Check for Delete for all content - check screen shot - https://www.screencast.com/t/pYJ6pHIkVEU

Comment: @RamGuru99 try this [`(?s)<p>.*?<.*?\shref="software-testing.html"\sonclick.*?<\/.*?>`](https://regex101.com/r/okQStc/3)

Comment: For this not working I have try this for it was working <a.*?\shref="software-testing.html"\sonclick.*?<\/.*?>

Comment: @RamGuru99 yes, it's pretty much the same that I gave in my answer.

Comment: There is not working (?s)<p>.*?<.*?\shref="software-testing.html"\sonclick.*?<\/.‌​*?>

Answer (score 0):

Another approach would be to use [simplehtmldom](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/):

```
<?php
require 'simple_html_dom.php';
$htmlString='<p>Testing is a key element to any application. 
<a href="software-testing.html" onclick="ga(\'send\', \'event\', \'internal\', \'Node.js\', \'Node.js\');"> Link1 </a> is called Jasmine. In early 2000, there was a framework for testing  JavaScript applications called JsUnit. Later this framework got upgraded and is now known as jasmine. </p>
<p>Jasmine helps in automated unit <a href="software-testing.html"> Link2 </a>';
$html = new simple_html_dom();
$html->load($htmlString);
$tags = $html->find('a[onclick][href=software-testing.html]');
$tags[0]->outertext=$tags[0]->innertext;
echo $html;
```

Comment: I have fetch data from database. not from url.

Comment: Yes this method allows you to get data from anywhere - see my example is just using a string